# What is "create mode 10064 <file>" in Git? Are there any other modes? What do they mean? Are there numbers other than 10064? What do they mean?

Tags: git, git-commit

As I was learning Git, I saw the commit message was able to understand what everything meant except this. I searched a bit on google and stack but there is no proper explanation as to what it means and the meaning of different modes or numbers displayed.

Comment: https://medium.com/@tahteche/how-git-treats-changes-in-file-permissions-f71874ca239d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+file+modes